# C++ fstream: get() skipping first and last line

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, iostream

I'm reading from a file of integers, converting each element in the file to an integer and adding the integer to a vector of vectors, if the file moves to a new line, the vector of vectors moves to a new vector. For example,  if the input file contains:

```
9
2 5 8
7 1 10
5 3
20 15 30
100 12
```

The vector of vectors should contain:

```
[ [9],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [7, 1, 10],
  [5, 3],
  [20, 15, 30],
  [100, 12] ]
```

However, the problem with my implementation is that it stores:

```
[ [2, 5, 8],
  [7, 1, 10],
  [5, 3],
  [20, 15, 30] ]
```

Causing the code to output:

```
2 5 8
7 1 10
5 3
20 15 30
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("input.txt"); // Opens input file.

    char currentChar;
    int currentInput = 0;
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    vector<int> vec2;

    while (inputFile.get(currentChar)) { // Reads each character of given file.

        if (currentChar == '\n') { // If current character is a new line, store current vec2 in vec and clear vec2
            vec.push_back(vec2);
            vec2.clear();
        }

        inputFile >> currentInput; // Current character to integer
        vec2.push_back(currentInput); // Adds current integer to vec2

    }
    vec2.clear();
    inputFile.close();

    for (const auto& inner : vec) { // Prints vector of vectors.
        for (auto value : inner) {
            cout << value << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on ways to fix this problem would help greatly.

Comment: `get()` reads the first character from the file. Once that '9' is read, it is read. It is gone. It is no longer in the file. It ceased to be. It's pining for the fjords. It's not longer a character in the file. So, the subsequent formatted extraction operator, `>>`, of course, doesn't read it. Which part of this is unclear to you?  This is a fundamentally wrong approach for doing this. You should be using `std::getline` to read one line at a time, can't get any simpler, then use `>>` to extract each int value in the line, and use it to construct a vector. This should be just 4-5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing around the while loop.

```
while (!inputFile.eof()) {

    inputFile >> currentInput;

    vec2.push_back(currentInput);

    if (inputFile.peek() == '\n' || inputFile.peek() == EOF) {
        vec.push_back(vec2);
        vec2.clear();
    }
}
```

I had troubles finding the next line and end of file. This was fixed by using the peek function to find '\n' and the end of file (EOF).

Answer (score 1):

I have used `std::istream::getline` to process file line by line.
Try this,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int , char *[]){

    std::ifstream stream("input.txt");
    std::istringstream other("");

    int i = 0;
    char buffer[100] = {};

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
    std::vector<int> vec;

    stream.getline(buffer, 100);

    while(stream.gcount() > 1){
        other.clear();
        other.str(buffer);

        while (other >> i) {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }

        if(!vec.empty()){
            data.push_back(std::move(vec));
        }

        stream.clear();
        stream.getline(buffer, 100);
    }

    for(const auto& ele: data){
        std::cout<< "[ ";
        for(int vecEle: ele){
            std::cout<< vecEle<< " ";
        }
        std::cout<< "]\n";
    }
}
```

output :

```
[ 9 ]
[ 2 5 8 ]
[ 7 1 10 ]
[ 5 3 ]
[ 20 15 30 ]
[ 100 12 ]
```

Comment: This is a working solution for my problem. Thanks for the help, however, I'm not sure if it's strictly a better or not, but I prefer my solution due to readability. This extra solution can broaden the range of help to reach others.

Comment: @Uz0r  Welcome, It is up to you to decide which solution is more good for you, And about my solution, i just put what i think to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!inputFile.eof(0)) {

    inputFile >> currentInput;

    vec2.push_back(currentInput);

    if (inputFile.peek() == '\n') {
        vec.push_back(503);
        vec2.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: 4679\ is this typo?